# LibreOffice date shift in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, date, odbc, libreoffice

I'm managing small PostgreSQL database. Recently I created new date field in one of tables. I'm working on pgAdminIII and everything is fine, but one of the users just reported that while working on LibreOffice *all dates are shifted* by 10 days to the past.

I just installed LibreOffice to check it and they are shifted on my copy too but by 9 days.

This is simple `date` field without any default value or constraints. All dates are before year 1900 (1400-1500).

In pgAdmin and console psql client everything is fine.

What can cause such an issue? How to fix that?

EDIT:

Problem occurs in table view only. I can access correct date via `Tools > SQL...` menu while viewing table data or creating query produces invalid results. It may be format conversion error (from `Y-M-D` to `D.M.Y`).

Comment: Examples? That's ... bizarre.

Comment: What does "on my copy" mean? How do you access the db? Which db driver? Which OS? Which LO version?

Comment: Probably LibreOffice is using Julian dates for dates before 15th October 1582

Comment: @CraigRinger All dates are just shifted. Every field is shifted by constant interval (different on different machines). For example: in DB it is `19.05.1497` in LO `10.05.1497`.

@tohuwawohu I mean - on my copy of LibreOffice, version  4.2.5.2 (downloaded and installed today). Database is on remote server which I access via ODBC. OS is Win7 in my case. I don't know about versions other users are running.

@ClodoaldoNeto date shift is not same on different computers/installations. On my it is 9 days, other user reports 10 days.

Comment: If you make a table of dates with `CREATE TABLE testdates AS SELECT x, x::text FROM generate_series(DATE '1400-01-01', current_date, INTERVAL '1' YEAR) x`, at what point does the gap appear, where the text and date representations start to differ?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto just tested, `1582-10-15` is correct, `1582-10-14` becomes `1582-10-04` on LibreOffice's side (using SDBC on windows for connection)

Comment: If you use the ODBC or JDBC drivers instead of direct (SDBC) do the results change?